# Created a Word 2007 Application level word add-in - does not work for new documents

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

I have created a Word add-in following the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx). I press F5 and run the project and It works as expected and I would think that the add-in has been installed in my machine. So, now I open another instance of Word 2007 and create a document and I dont see that code working on the new document. Am I missing something?

Following is the code I am using :-

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.DocumentBeforeSave +=
   new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler(Application_DocumentBeforeSave);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
            Doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text = "Text was added by using code.---";
        }


        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);


        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx#Y1146):-
*When you finish developing a project, remove the add-in assembly, registry entries, and security settings from your development computer. Otherwise, the add-in will continue to run every time that you open Word on your development computer.
To clean up the completed project on your development computer
In Visual Studio, on the Build menu, click Clean Solution.*

Now, when I dont clean the solution, I should have the add-in for the Word 2007 all the time, right? I don't see that happening at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the way you are doing things there are a few possibilities.

Most likely is that when you open the new instance, the debugger isn't attached, so your breakpoints are not being hit.

Another possible reason is that it is not a new instance but actually a new document in the same instance, and the the same instance of the same add-in is shared between the two documents. In that case ThisAdd.Loaded event will not be fired again, you have to listen for new documents being activated (from memory word doesn't have a NewDocument event)

What sort of code is not working? Is it the effects that cannot be seen, or a breakpoint not being hit?

Comment: I didn't talk about the debug. I create the plug in and It works on the debug. After I am done with running the sample, the plug-in should get installed in my machine and would work for the documents which I open later- isn't it? Thats why I am trying to create an app level plug-in.

Comment: As long as you created an application level add-in first, then yes it should work fine. What does your add-in do, need more info to try and figure it?

Comment: It just adds a line in the word in the this.Application.DocumentBeforeSave event. It looks like as long as I am in the debug mode the code executes as expected. However, when I am not debugging and I try to open a new document and try to save the same, the line is not getting written by the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

I see that removing that add-in from word 2007 resolves the problem. If you face this problem, try removing the add-in from Word 2007 and build the solution the solution again and your change will take effect. For some reason "Clean solution" does not remove the word add-in sometimes (atleast sometimes in my case :-))

[image]

[image]